# How can I redirect to a new page in lift

Tags: scala, redirect, lift

I am a total newbie in Scala and Lift, I've been working with that for 2 months only, so I have a lot of trouble with some stuff. I've been reading simply lift and the definitive guide to lift, but I tried the methods to redirect to another page when pressing a button with no success.

Here's the code I have until now:

class BL_LOG001S {

```
object Log extends Logger

var lang_id = 1//English
var ido = IDO_LOG001
var odo = ODO_LOG001
var usr = new User
var input_usr = DAO_LOGIN_USER_001.create

def init = {

    Log.info("INIT 1: LANG_ID: "+lang_id)
    lang_id = usr.lang_id
    Log.info("INIT 2: LANG_ID: "+ lang_id)

}

def title = {
    Log.info("TITLE: INIT END:")
    <h2>{odo.body("title").toLabel(lang_id)}</h2>
    <span>{usr.login_nm.toString}</span>
}

def login() = {

    <table>
        {odo.body("organization_nm").toTableElement(lang_id)}
        {odo.body("login_nm").toTableElement(lang_id)}
        {odo.body("password").toTableElement(lang_id)}
    </table>
}

def transaction() = {
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><LOG001_1:submit><button>Login</button></LOG001_1:submit>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}

def display(form: NodeSeq) = {
    <lift:BL_LOG001.execute form="post" multipart="true">
        {login}
        {transaction}
    </lift:BL_LOG001.execute>

}

def execute(form: NodeSeq) = {
    doBind(form)

}
def checkAndLogin(): Unit = {

        Log.info("Check: init: organization_nm = "+input_usr.organization_nm)
        ido.body("organization_nm").setValue(input_usr.organization_nm)
        ido.body("login_nm").setValue(input_usr.login_nm)
        ido.body("password").setValue(input_usr.password)
        usr.login(ido.body("organization_nm").getValue.toString,
                ido.body("login_nm").getValue.toString,
                ido.body("password").getValue.toString)
        S.redirectTo("/AdminPage/ADM001")
}

def doBind(form: NodeSeq) = {
    bind("LOG001_1", form,
            "organization_nm" -> input_usr.organization_nm.toForm,
            "login_nm" -> input_usr.login_nm.toForm,
            "password" -> input_usr.password.toForm,
            "submit" -> SHtml.submit("Login", checkAndLogin))

}
```

}

The method checkAndLogin has S.redirectTo, but it does not redirect to the page I need. What I need is to capture the organization and login name, and show them in the next page.

I'm sorry if I am asking something stupid. I would really appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

have you tried method **RedirectTo** of object **JsCmds**? [[doc of this here]](http://main.scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.2/framework/scaladocs/net/liftweb/http/js/JsCmds%24object.html)

Maybe it helps you.

For future - for problems strictly connected to Lift framework I recommend to ask on [Lift forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb), where are all Lift experts and they are very helpful for every Lift developer, especially for newbies :)

good luck